# I am trying to make an application from github but getting an error

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, cmake

This is the application I am trying to Make [pokerstove](https://github.com/andrewprock/pokerstove). I am following instructions on how to make it on linux platform but getting error when doing the make command.

```
usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file
 requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard.
This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the 
-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
 #error This file requires compiler and library support for the \
```

I tried using the flags

```
sudo make CPPFLAGS+="-std=c++11 ..."
```

But it does not work. Can somebody help please.

Thank you

Comment: You should not need `sudo` to run `make` and may in fact be introducing problems by doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With CMake project you may change compilation flags by passing them to `cmake` executable:

```
cmake "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-std=c++11" <source-dir>
```